# Trying to receive file from mat-dialog angular in parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to receive file from mat-dialog which has input for files. But have some problems. Help me please.

Parent component.ts:

```
export class TimelineComponent implements OnInit {
  cvList = [];
  ngOnInit() {
  }
addCv() {
    const dialogNew = this.dialog.open(NewCvDialogComponent, {
      data: {...this.cvList}
    });

    dialogNew.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.cvList.push(result);
      }
    });
  }
 }
```

Mat-dialog component.html:

```
<div class="dialog">
  <h2 mat-dialog-title>Attach CV</h2>
  <form fxLayout="column" #form="ngForm">
      <input
        type="file"
        accept=".doc,.docx,.txt,.pdf"
        placeholder="Input file"
        name="input-file"
        [(ngModel)]="data.file"
        (change)="addCV($event)"
        required
      />
  </form>
  <div
    mat-dialog-actions
    fxLayout="row nowrap"
    fxLayoutGap="10px"
    class="actions"
  >
    <button
      mat-raised-button
      color="warn"
      [mat-dialog-close]="false"
      fxFlex="50"
    >
      Cancel
    </button>
    <button
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
      [mat-dialog-close]="data"
      cdkFocusInitial
      fxFlex="50"
      [disabled]="form.invalid"
    >
      Save
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I using this in result I getting only filename. I want to receive all object with name, size and etc. How I can to do it?

Comment: is this addCV function in parent component?

Comment: can you do this in a [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? so its easier to understand

Comment: @AkhiAkl Yeah, Here you can see an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjk2b6 . Finaly, in console I getting Array of Objects with field file only, but i want to recieve full information about file, including name, size, data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In dialog component I just add a variable with inputed file and passed it to parent using [mat-dialog-close]

Answer (score 0):

You get the filepath as string right? the solution is to change the file into string and pass data into **parent component**.

In your ***mat-dialogue.component.ts***  add this  file event function

```
      convertTostring(event){


    let reader = new FileReader();

    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = () => {

        this.cvv = reader.result;
      };
    }
  }
```

***mat-dialogue.component.html***

and change the template into **[mat-dialog-close]="[data, cvv]"**

```
 <button
  mat-raised-button
  color="primary"
  [mat-dialog-close]="[data, cvv]"
  cdkFocusInitial
  fxFlex="50"
  [disabled]="form.invalid">
  Save
</button>
```

finally you can get the data in **parent.component.ts**

```
 addCv() {
    const dialogNew = this.dialog.open(NewCvDialogComponent, {
      data: {...this.cvList}
    });

    dialogNew.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      if (result) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
```